# Is there a standard hotkey grabber dialog in Qt?

Tags: qt, hotkeys

Is there a standard hotkey grabber dialog in Qt like the standard color picker dialog? Something like the compiz key grabber dialog:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a hotkey grabber dialog?  I don't know what kind of dialog you're talking about.

Comment: Hi, I meant something like the compiz keygrabber dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, at least for now - you can contribute it :). [Qt 4.7 Standard Dialogs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/standard-dialogs.html)

Comment: I'll settle for QInputDialog then :)

Answer (score 1):

You can give a look at the Qt designer source: they have a grab key combination when you edit a QAction.